# Can I mark 3 different dates with mui date picker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

as far as I can see from the MuiDatePicker documentation, it can only show one date,
but I want it to show 3 different dates from the api, like to do list. I will be glad
if you can help me with this.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider'
import { StaticDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/StaticDatePicker'
import { StyledContainer } from './index.styles'

export default function Reminders() {
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date())

return (
<StyledContainer>
  <div className="reminders_title">Reminders</div>
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <StaticDatePicker
      orientation="landscape"
      openTo="day"
      value={value}
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue)
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
 </StyledContainer>
 )
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You can mark as many dates as you like. The solution depends on *how* you want to mark them.

If you only want to mark them on the dates within the calendar, you can use the `<StaticDatePicker>` **renderDay** property. If you want to mark them elsewhere (e.g. the Toolbar or a footer) you might have to provide a custom Toolbar title or design your own custom Toolbar or footer.

The rest of this post assumes you only want to mark the dates within the calendar.

According to the [documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#props) the *renderDay* property is a function with the following signature:

> *day*: The day to render.
> *selectedDays*: The days currently selected.
> *pickersDayProps*: The props of the day to render.
> returns (JSX.Element): The element representing the day.

Please note that marking three dates is not the same as the date picker's *value* having three dates. The date picker is a component that makes it easy for users to input one single date. It is up to you to manage that user input however you like. You may wish to use React.useState() to manage an array of three date values. Or you may wish to use Redux. Whatever you choose, you have to manage the three dates. The StaticDatePicker will not do that for you. The StaticDatePicker can display data as you choose based on how you apply styles to the dates in the calendar. You apply styles to the dates using properties of the `<PickersDay>` component.

The `<PickersDay>` component (or a higher order component that wraps it) is returned from the **renderDay** function. Based on whether or not the date to be rendered matches one of your three dates, you can apply a DOM Element id or class name to the root of the `<PickersDay>` component. Your CSS would then apply the desired styles. If you wanted to apply the styling Material-UI uses to indicate a selected date, just use the Global class names Material-UI uses for its StaticDatePicker.

Unfortunately, the [API documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/) for the latest version (@mui/x-date-pickers) of the `<DatePicker>` component does not document the Global class names. But, you can find them using the Inspector tab of the Firefox Developer Tools. The class used to style a selected date is **.Mui-selected**.

Sample code could look like this:

```js
// Using React.useState(), 'dateArray' is the state variable used to store the
// dates you consider to be selected. 'dateArray' should be updated using the
// 'setDateArray()' function based on code you provide to validate the dates
// chosen by the user. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html for more
// on using React.useState().
// 'initial_values' could be empty, could come from a database, etc.
const [ dateArray, setDateArray ] = React.useState( [ initial_values ] );

...

<StyledContainer>
    <div className="reminders_title">Reminders</div>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <StaticDatePicker
            orientation="landscape"
            openTo="day"
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
                setValue(newValue)
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
            renderDay={(day, selectedDays, pickersDayProps) => {
                let selectedMuiClass = '';

                // Pseudo-code here! You will have to use the proper functions from the
                // date-fns library to evaluate if 'day' is in your dateArray.
                if ( dateArray.includes( day ) ) { 
                    selectedMuiClass = 'Mui-selected';
                }

                return (
                    <PickersDay
                        className={ selectedMuiClass }
                        { ...pickersDayProps }
                    /> 
                );
            }}
        />
    </LocalizationProvider>
 </StyledContainer>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The renderDay property doesn't seem to exist anymore as its missing in the [documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/static-date-picker/). For customizing the StaticDatePicker component now, please refer to [this site](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/) and the 'slots' property.

If you want to view an example, I refactored the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814384/21434824).