# Can not visualise badge with check icon in MUI DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I am using MUI Date Picker and React.js for this project.

The problem I have is that I can not visualise a checkIcon that should be rendered as a badge based on highlighted dates that are currently a dummy array.

I am not able to find any specific info in the documentation and tried following video explanations but nothing seems to work.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { StaticDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/StaticDatePicker';
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import { PickersDay } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/PickersDay';
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';

export const Calendar = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date());
  const [highlightedDays, setHighlightedDays] = useState([1, 2, 13]);

  return (
   
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <StaticDatePicker
        variant='static'
        orientation='portrait'
        value={value}
        disableFuture
        onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        renderInput={(params) => {
          <TextField {...params} />;
        }}
        renderDay={(day, _value, DayComponentProps) => {
          const isSelected =
            !DayComponentProps.outsideCurrentMonth &&
            highlightedDays.indexOf(day.getDate()) >= 0;

          return (
            <Badge
              key={day.toString()}
              overlap='circular'
              badgeContent={isSelected ? <CheckIcon color='red' /> : undefined}
            >
              <PickersDay {...DayComponentProps} />
            </Badge>
          )
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/static-date-picker/) and somehow, there isn't any of the props 'renderDay', 'renderInput' or 'variant' in the StaticDatePicker component.

Instead, you should customize your StaticDatePicker with the slots property. You can view more information on the customization options [here](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/).

I refactored your code to work with the slots property like so:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  LocalizationProvider,
  PickersDay,
  StaticDatePicker,
} from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { Badge } from "@mui/material";
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';

export const Calendar = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date());
  const [highlightedDays, setHighlightedDays] = useState([1, 2, 13]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <StaticDatePicker
        orientation="portrait"
        value={value}
        disableFuture
        onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        slots={{
          day: (props) => {
            const isSelected = !props.outsideCurrentMonth && highlightedDays.indexOf(props.day.getDate()) >= 0;
          
            return (
              <Badge
                key={props.day.toString()}
                overlap="circular"
                badgeContent={isSelected ? <CheckIcon htmlColor="red" /> : undefined}
              >
                <PickersDay {...props} />
              </Badge>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};
```

Now everything seems to work, the days 1, 2 and 13 get correctly highlighted with a red check.

Comment: Michel, you are a hero! Thank you so much! I guess I got lost somewhere along the way

Comment: Thank you Michel, really practical! But I wanted to know if it was possible to highlight the days exactly like when I'm on a day rather than making a badge?

Comment: Should be pretty simple. Just remove the `Badge` Element and add some style with the `sx` property of `PickersDay`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the ability to choose different days using DateCalendar, here is the solution:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { LocalizationProvider, PickersDay } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { DateCalendar } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateCalendar";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";

export const Calendar = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<Date | null>(null);

  const refDates = useRef<number[]>([]);
  const handleSetNewVal = (date: Date | null) => {
    
    if (!date) return;
    setValue(date);
    const pickedDay = new Date(date).getTime();
    const refsDays = refDates.current;
    const inxPickedDay = refsDays.indexOf(pickedDay);
    if (inxPickedDay >= 0) {
      refsDays.splice(inxPickedDay, 1);
    } else {
      refsDays.push(pickedDay);
    }
  };

  const [pickedDates, setPickedDates] = useState<number[]>([]);
  console.log("dates", pickedDates);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPickedDates(refDates.current);
  }, [refDates.current.length]);


  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DateCalendar
        value={value}
        disablePast
        onChange={(newValue) => handleSetNewVal(newValue)}
        slots={{
          day: (props) => {
            const dayNumber = new Date(props.day).getTime();
            const refDays = refDates.current;
            const isSelected = refDays.indexOf(dayNumber) >= 0;
            return <PickersDay {...props} selected={isSelected} />;
          },
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).